# How to make ng-select's list of options render with the current "selected" attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

There's an example of using `ng-select` in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select), included as a snippet below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.colors = [
      {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'white', shade:'light'},
      {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
    ];
    $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2]; // red
  }]);
</script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors"></select>
  <p>Selected: {{myColor}}</p>
</div>
```

But when you select a different color than the default (red) the HTML is still rendered with

```
<option value="2" selected="selected">red</option>
```

Is this wrong? If so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that this is not rendered wrong.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option):

> **selected**
>
> If present, this Boolean attribute indicates that the option
>   is initially selected. If the  element is the descendant of
>   a element whose multiple attribute is not set, only one single
>    of this  element may have the selected attribute.

From the [HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element):

> The selected attribute is a boolean attribute. It represents the default selectedness of the element.

Both state that `selected` represents the default/initial state of the `<option>` element, not its current state.